# setState asynchronously in React Component

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-state

I have a React component which is pulling an API from an express url, `/profile/:id`.  I am receiving the data correctly via the API. Additionally, the logging in the browser supports that the state of `data` and `urls` is set correctly.

However, the `render()` function is throwing an error because of this line `this.state.urls.map((url) =>`.  I'm assuming the error is happening because the rendering is occurring before the state is set (even though I'm using `componentDidMount`).

What changes do I need to make to allow the render function's item line to iterate over `urls` array?

The error I'm seeing is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'urls')`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {  Tabs } from 'antd';

export class TestResults extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super (props);
        
    }
    getProfileData (){
        const fetchAndSetData = async () => {
          const response = await fetch('/profile/' + this.props.profileId);
          this.setState({data: await response.json()})
          console.log(`States ${JSON.stringify(this.state)}`)
          this.setState({urls: this.getUrls()});
        }
        fetchAndSetData()
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getProfileData();
    }
    getUrls(){
        const urls = [];
        console.log("Calling URLs " + JSON.stringify(this.state))
        for (var x = 0; x < this.state.data.length; x++){
            urls.push(this.state.data[x].url)
        }
        console.log("URLs are " + urls)
        return urls
    }
    render (){
        
        return(
            <div>
                <Tabs
                    defaultActiveKey="1"
                    type="card"
                    size="large"
                    items={this.state.urls.map((url) => {
                      return {
                          label: `${url}`,
                          key: 1,
                          children: `Somne content for ${url}`,
                      };
                  })}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m afraid that there is few errors in your code. (1) you should call `this.state` only once in the `constructor`. (2) Add `async` before `getProfileData` function. (3) replace `this.state` by `this.setState` in `getProfileData`. (4) Why importing `useState` from `react` since you are using class based component? Hooks only work with functional component.

Comment: Thanks for the notes.  I'm new to react, so learning on the fly.  I've made the updates as suggested though still not working as expected.

Comment: Can you update your question?

Comment: "the render() function is throwing an error ..." What is the error? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: I assume the error is something like "cannot call `map` on `undefined`". One solution for this is to initialize `urls` as an empty array.

Comment: setState is a function you don't do `this.setState = ` please take a look at some examples of a working component..

Comment: Changed setState to a function. Also, the error is map undefined.

Comment: @Gerg you do not ever call `fetchAndSetData()`. and `componentDidMount()` is executed *after* the first `render()`

Comment: @Gerg You should copy/paste the exact error into your original question rather than summarizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Optional Chaining

You guessed it right. The problem is `urls` array is [undefined](/questions/tagged/undefined) when `map()` method get called.

so you cloud check whether it is undefined by using `?` `Optional Chaining`

```
this?.state?.urls?.map(...)
```

### React Functional Component

With functional component managing the code will be much easier.so I thought why not add some codes.

```
const TestResults () => {

    const [data,setData] = useState({})
    const [urls,setUrls] = useState([])
    const [profileId,setProfileId] = useState([])

    async getProfileData (){
        const fetchAndSetData = async () => {
          const response = await fetch('/profile/' + profiled);
          const fetched = await response.json()
          setData(fetched)
          setUrls(fetched.map(item=> item.url));
        }
    }
 
   useEffect(()=>{
     getProfileData ()
   },[])
  
   return(
        <div>
            <Tabs
                defaultActiveKey="1"
                type="card"
                size="large"
                items={urls?.map(url => {label: `${url}`,key: 1,children: `Somne content for ${url}`,
              })}
             />
         </div>
   )

}
```

Comment: Is `?.` an operator in JavaScript or is that only available for TypeScript?

Comment: It's on javascript standarads.[`Documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: The optional chaining fixed it.  Thanks for all the advice everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set `urls` to an empty list initially. In the constructor you can do:

```
this.state = {urls: []}
```